# Moving object using keyboard qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to move an object using my arrow keys, but when I launch the app, nothing happens. Do you have an idea on how to fix it ?

@Update :  my rectangle only moves once to the left and to the right, but if I use qDebug it recognizes all the times I click left or right, any ideas ?

```
void MouvementJoueur::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
switch ( e->key() )
    {
    case Qt::Key_Left:
        rectangle->setPos(x()-10,y());
        qDebug() << "You pressed the Key left";
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Right:
        rectangle->setPos(x()+10,y());
        qDebug() << "You pressed the Key right";
        break;
    }
 }
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: "nothing happens" is rather vague error description. If that is indeed true, literally nothing seems to happen, problem is most likely in main function, such as never calling the event loop.

Comment: You should try to provide an MCVE if possible. Also, if you wish for others to read your code, it is highly recommended you indent it properly. It's just basic courtesy towards those who you wish to help you. All commonly used Qt IDEs (Qt Creator, Visual Studio, KDevelop...) have auto-indent or code formatting so there is no excuse to post poorly formatted code to Stack Overflow here.

Comment: @hyde I dit it but still I had to insert spaces in stackoverflow and idk why and what I mean is that if I click the right or left arrow, my rectangle does not move. What do you suggest?

Comment: To get the code formatted properly at SO, just paste it to the question edit textbox with your original correct indentation, and with empty lines below and above. Then select the entire code snippet, and click the code formatting icon `{}`, or keyboard shortcut ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be, that you take position of the parent, and set position of rectangle based on that. This is probably not what you want to do with key presses here. You should set the position like this:

```
rectangle->setPos(rectangle->x() - 10, rectangle->y());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the GUI with the following command

```
view->processEvents();
```

and you can debug it. It detect the key press or not.

```
void MouvementJoueur::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
  if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
  {
    rectangle->setPos(x()-10,y());
    qDebug() << "You pressed the Key x";
  } 

  if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
  {
    rectangle->setPos(x()+10,y());
    qDebug() << "You pressed the Key x";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it recognizes but my rectangle isnt shown on the screen, its invisible..